# How remove duplicated Python versions from MacOS Mojave

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio Code on MacOS Mojave. However, I've noticed app finds 4(!) versions of Python. I don't know why Python 3.7.x is duplicated and have no idea how can it be deleted.

[image: VSCode recognization]

Comment: not sure if related? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22006

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to search for each version within the computer using the search icon, located within the menu bar on the top right of your screen. Search for the unwanted versions and it will give you an option to delete.